# Durandal: accessing child router functions from the shell

Tags: javascript, shell, router, durandal

In router.map, I have the following:

```js
{ route: '01_02_003*details', moduleId: 'viewmodels/chapter2/01_02_003', title: 'Chapter 2 Page 3', nav: true },
```

In shell.js I have the following. Everything with the child router works, but I want the Next and Back buttons in shell.js to be able to duplicate the functionality of the inner Next and Back buttons inside of 1.js, 2.js, 3.js, 4.js, and 5.js, which are the child router viewmodels. Is there any way to reference the child router viewmodel functions from shell.js? From the child router I can just call $shell.functionNameHere or $shell.observableNameHere, but the reverse doesn't seem to work.

```js
        createChapter2Router: function() {
            if (!$shell.chapter2Router) {
                $shell.chapter2Router = router.createChildRouter()
                    .makeRelative({
                    moduleId: 'viewmodels/chapter2/childRouter',
                    fromParent: true
                }).map([
                    { route: ['', '1'], moduleId: '1', title: 'Chapter 2 - Child Router', type: 'intro', nav: true },
                    { route: ['2'], moduleId: '2', title: 'Chapter 2 - Child Router', type: 'intro', nav: true },
                    { route: ['3'], moduleId: '3', title: 'Chapter 2 - Child Router', type: 'intro', nav: true },
                    { route: ['4'], moduleId: '4', title: 'Chapter 2 - Child Router', type: 'intro', nav: true },
                    { route: ['5'], moduleId: '5', title: 'Chapter 2 - Child Router', type: 'intro', nav: true },
                ]).buildNavigationModel();
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be coupling the children quite tightly to the shell if you did that. The best way to achieve what you're asking for here, is to use the [event pub/sub capability of Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Leveraging-Publish-Subscribe.html).

In essence, each child viewmodel will subscribe to events when it loads, and unsubscribe when it is closed. The shell has the forward/back buttons on it, and when they're clicked, simply publishes "ForwardNavigationRequested" or "BackwardNavigationRequested" events, which the current child page then deal with accordingly.